# Passing Javascript Variables to a PHP Server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm having some real difficulty with this, I've been searching for hours and hours and I'm having trouble understand.
I know there are other questions like this but I think I need some context help.

The aim is: Everytime a user attempts a quiz, the score they receive will be recorded as a separate record in the attempts table.

I have the following pages:

> quiz_form.php, quiz_process.php and quiz.js

The score that I need to pass through to the php, is calculated in the JS file, passed through HTML in results.php and displayed. I need to get this variable, somehow into quiz_process and put it into a table.

Quiz_form.php:

```
<form id="quiz" method="get" class="detailsform" novalidate="novalidate" action="quiz_process.php">

****** QUESTION CODE HERE *****

    <input class="button" type="button" id="chkans" value="Check Answers" />
    <input class="button" type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

quiz.js

```
function sumbit_answers()
{
    store_answers();
    sessionStorage.result = mark_answers();
    alert(sessionStorage.result);
    document.getElementById("result").value = sessionStorage.result;

    alert("You have finished the quiz. Please click OK to go to the results page.");
    window.location.href="quiz_process.php";
}
```

quiz_process.php

```
<?php
require_once("settings.php");

session_start();
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
$result = $_GET["result"];
echo $email; echo $result;

?>
```

Email is getting through and it's showing but result seems to be very hesitant.
Thank you for any help, I'm sorry for posting but it's 3AM and it's doing my head in.

Comment: can you tell where you call that function of quiz.js?

Comment: Insert a hidden input with the value of the score before submit is executed. delete `window.location.href="quiz_process.php";`.

Comment: I call that function after the button click of submit of the form

Comment: @rookie - Been trying that, think it executes too late or I'm naming it wrong. EDIT: Giving it another go now. Only thing is, last time I did that, it didn't submit it to Quiz_process

Comment: where do you call `sumbit_answers()`? typo?

Comment: @rookie - Within `function init()` which consists of `document.getElementById("submit").onclick = sumbit_answers`

Comment: @rookie - I've done what you've said with the hidden field. I changed it to a normal text field and it's reading the score correctly. It's not posting to the php server, or redirecting at all. EDIT: Fixed this

Comment: yep, got it. Thanks for your help! I wandered away from your suggestion but it was right all along! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was with the submit button, it was set to type="button" not type="submit".

Comment: I find a quick nap or a short walk helps with code blindness ;)